# Integral Equation $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(y)}{1+(x-y)^2}\mathrm dy =0 \quad \forall x$

Tags: integration

I want to calculate $f(y)$ such that 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(y)}{1+(x-y)^2}\mathrm dy =0 \quad \forall x$$

Can we prove that the solution to this problem is $f(y)=0?$

Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$
$\widetilde{\vphantom{\large A}\cdots}$ ( tilde's ) are Fourier Transforms.
\begin{align}
0
&=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dd x\,\expo{-\ic kx}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty {{\rm f}\pars{y} \over 1 + \pars{x - y}^{2}}\,\dd y
=
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dd x\,{\rm f}\pars{y}\expo{-\ic ky}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty {\expo{-\ic kx} \over \pars{x - \ic}\pars{x + \ic}}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=
\tilde{\rm f}\pars{k}\pi\expo{-\verts{k}}
\quad\imp\quad
\tilde{\rm f}\pars{k} = 0
\quad\imp\quad
{\rm f}\pars{x} = 0
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much. However this solution is valid for the $f(y)$s that their fourier transform converge. A function like $f(y)$ may exist that satisfy our equation and have diverging Fourier transform.

Comment: @Mamal Yes. It's true. I didn't mention that but it was obvious that is valid whenever the Fourier transform exists.

Comment: Can we prove that the $f(y)$s satisfying this equation have to convergne in terms of Fourier transform?

Comment: @Mamal It's an interesting question. I don't know the answer.